# how to store array in array php

Tags: php, arrays

i'm having some problem with in arrays.
i have 3 arrays. i want to make 1 row called history then it insert that row based on shipment_id. if same shipment_id it will group same shipment id. See expected result below.

```
Array a ( 
 [0] => Array ( 
    [order_id] => 231 
    [name] => "One Layer Lunch Box 
    [quantity] => 1 
    [username] => linkath 
    [shipment_id] => SI000116 ) 
 [1] => Array ( 
    [order_id] => 231 
    [name] => "Test 03 
    [quantity] => 1 
    [username] => happymart 
    [shipment_id] => SI000117 ) )
Array b ( 
 [0] => Array ( 
    [shipment_id] => SI000116
    [date] => 2016-11-09 09:40:26 
    [status] => Ready to ship 
    [description] => Your item(s) is being packed and ready for shipment at our vendor's warehouse. ) 
 [1] => Array ( 
    [shipment_id] => SI000116
    [date] => 2016-11-09 10:16:04 
    [status] => Shipped 
    [description] => Your item(s) is being shipped with . For more details on your shipment, please go to Tracking, enter your tracking number ) )
Array c ( 
 [0] => Array ( 
    [shipment_id] => SI000117
    [date] => 2016-11-09 15:27:45 
    [status] => Ready to ship 
    [description] => Your item(s) is being packed and ready for shipment at our vendor's warehouse. ) )
```

As expected array

```
Array a ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [order_id] => 231 
    [name] => "One Layer Lunch Box 
    [quantity] => 1 
    [username] => linkath 
    [shipment_id] => SI000116
    [history] => Array b ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [shipment_id] => SI000116
                    [date] => 2016-11-09 09:40:26 
                    [status] => Ready to ship 
                    [description] => Your item(s) is being packed and ready for shipment at our vendor's warehouse. ) 
                [1] => Array ( 
                    [shipment_id] => SI000116
                    [date] => 2016-11-09 10:16:04 
                    [status] => Shipped 
                    [description] => Your item(s) is being shipped with . For more details on your shipment, please go to Tracking, enter your tracking number ) ) ) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [order_id] => 231 
    [name] => "Test 03 
    [quantity] => 1 
    [username] => happymart 
    [shipment_id] => SI000117 
    [history] => Array c ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [shipment_id] => SI000117
                    [date] => 2016-11-09 15:27:45 
                    [status] => Ready to ship 
                    [description] => Your item(s) is being packed and ready for shipment at our vendor's warehouse. ) )
            ) 
    )
```

Hopefully understand what i mean. Thanks in advance.

this code that im have tried. but not working.

```
//tracker
        $getshipment = $this->model_account_order->getshipmentByOrder($this->request->get['order_id']);

        foreach ($getshipment as $shipment) {
            $data['shipment'][] = array(
                'shipment_id'   => $shipment['shipment_id']
            );
        }
        $i=0;
        foreach ($data['shipment'] as $key) {
            $gethistorybysid[$i] = $this->model_account_order->getHistory($data['shipment'][$i]['shipment_id']);
            $i++;
        }
        $u=0;
        foreach ($getshipment as $final) {
            $data['final'][] = array(
                'name'          => $shipment['name'],
                'quantity'      => $shipment['quantity'],
                'shipment_id'   => $shipment['shipment_id'],
                'history'       => array($gethistorybysid[$u])
            );
            $u++;
        }
        print_r($data['final']);
```

this code i dont know how to compare same shipment id. Is it got any ways?

Comment: Can't help with your output ! Should post your tried code ...

Comment: @jitendrapurohit..im paste the code that im have tried.

Comment: @DavidJorHpan..pasted it..

Comment: @ZackZeidy Can you check the answer if it works for you ?

Comment: @jitendrapurohit nope. the history row didnt appear..

Answer (score 1):

You may use simple `foreach()` and [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to attain the result you want. Can you try the below approach, must work.

```
//Loop the main Array A as follows
foreach ($arrayA as $val) {
  //Take the array B and C in a loop and check for shipment Id
  foreach (array($arrayB, $arrayC) as $history) {
    // Push the array in history key(of Array A) if the match is found.
    if (in_array($val['shipment_id'], array_column($history, 'shipment_id')) {
      foreach ($history as $value) {
        $val['history'][] = $value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is just an idea, I think this should work, if not, you can modify as per your need.

Comment: Why didn't I think of `array_column`, I always seem to forget this function exists.

Answer (score 0):

As for the desired output:

```
# `array` is your first array where you want the shipments to be merged in.
# `array_b` is the array containing the history.

foreach($array as $contents){
    if(isset($contents['shipment_id'])){
        unset($match);
        foreach($array_b as $key => $value){
            if(isset($value['shipment_id'])){
                if($value['shipment_id'] == $contents['shipment_id']){
                    $match[] = $value['shipment_id'];
                }
            }
        }
        if(!empty($match)){
          $contents['shipment_id'] = $match;
        }
    }
}
```

This method will also retain the value of `shipment_id` when no history is found.

However, making a sepperate column like [jitendrapurohit's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40520518/4982088) answer is a much better solution.